# Javascript - How to return string from a function by using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-operator

I need to get string / title from last `product` in my `array` but only after I filter all my items to get only **active** products, and I've tried something like this:

```
function getProductNoteTitle() {
if (data.product && data.product.length>0) {
  var result = data.product.filter(
    item => item.productStatusId === ProductStatusEnum.Active
  );
  result.length > 0 ? return([result.length - 1].title) : return 'Not Set';
 }
}
```

But this wont work because I got an error on this line:

```
result.length > 0 ? return([result.length - 1].title) : return 'Not Set';
```

which says Expression expected.

Comment: `return` is not keyword that forms an expression, you cannot use it as the operand of something else. You want to `return (… ? … : …);` instead - notice the `return …;` being a statement.

Comment: @Bergi True mate! Thanks a lot for this nice explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work for you:

```
return result.length > 0 ? [result.length - 1].title : 'Not Set';
```